# Unable to Retrieve Multiple image in Django Post detail Page after succesfull upload in admin page

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I have a BLOG/NEWS website with the following Model.py, Views.py and and a post_detail.html page which i can successfully upload an image or file in the admin page panel when creating a post  but cannot retrieve the image in my post_detail.html page.

> I mean am unable to Retrieve Multiple image on my blog Post when i do the following code and after a succesful upload of images on the admin panel .

*I need help in solving this problem amicably.
And i have my admin.py configured accurately which make provision for uploading multiple images on a specific post in django*

**Models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
       image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/")
       title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
       summary = models.CharField(max_length=250)



class PostImage(models.Model): 
     post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     images = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='images')

     @property
     def image_url(self):
     return self.get_absolute_url()

     def get_absolute_url(self):
     return self.image.url
```

**Views.py**

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
model = Post

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['related_posts'] = Post.objects.filter(category=self.object.category).order_by('?')[:2]
    Context['multiple_image']= PostImage.objects.all()
    return context
```

**post_detail.html**

```
<div class="w-full md:flex md:-mx-2 ">
    {% for image in mutiple_images %}
    <div class="w-full md:w-1/2 px-2">
      <a href="{{ postimage.get_absolute_url }}">
        <img class="object-cover w-full h-24 m-2 rounded-lg" src="{{ postimage.images.url }}" alt=""> </a>

      </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
```

*Unfortuanately the image refuse to appear in the detail page and i strongly believe am definitely doing something wrong here.*

How do i make uploaded images appear on this panel.

**I await help and solutions**

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things that will get you closer:

1. Typo in Views. Change capitalization of Context['multiple_image']
2. In your template you're using 'image' as your loop variable so change postimage. references to image. like this: postimage.get_absolute_url to image.get_absolute_url
3. Your PostImage.objects.all() will pull all uploaded images in that model, so you'll probably want to filter that queryset to images for a specific post.

Comment: Your answer  named number three(3)  is not clear to me sir. Please kindly explain to me how to filter quereset images for a specific post  by specific post

Comment: It looks like you're trying to do something very similar to the examples provided in Django's documentation. You can find some examples here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

Comment: There is probably no documentations with a clearer answer